# Call `super` on JavaScript instance method

Tags: javascript, oop, babeljs, parceljs

I'm attempting to call `super` on an instance method of an ES6 style class, and I'm getting parcel/babel build errors.

```
@parcel/transformer-babel: 'super' is only allowed in object methods and classes. (1291:21)
```

My code effectively looks like this

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor(params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    matches(other) {
        // do some matching logic
        return true; // or false
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    matches(other) {
        let match = super.matches(other);
        // do some additional matching logic
        return true; // or false
    }

}
```

The error is when I call `super.matches(other)` in `MyClass`.

All the documentation I can find on `super` talks about its use in `constructor`, which is fine, and its use in `static` methods, but I have found no mention of instance methods.

Does this just not work in JS, am I doing it wrong, or is it something to do with the babel transformer or parcel?

Comment: Since the code runs perfectly fine in a modern browser it looks like a problem with your build process.

Comment: This works in JS, therefor it has something to do with babel transformer/parcel

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right.  Weirdly I have found situations where the same syntax doesn't cause the build error, so further digging required.

Answer (score 1):

Parcel v2 supports transpiling es6 class syntax by default using [`swc`](https://github.com/swc-project/swc). One "gotcha" is that if it detects a `.babelrc`/`babel.config.json` file in your project, it will switch to transpiling using babel, and then it is up to you to make sure that the config you provided will transpile classes.

According to [the docs](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#babel):

> if you're only using `@babel/preset-env`, `@babel/preset-typescript`, and `@babel/preset-react`, Babel may no longer be necessary. Parcel supports all of these features automatically without a Babel config, and Parcel's default transpiler is much faster than Babel.

So the first thing I would try is just deleting any `.babelrc`/`babel.config.json` files in your project so you can try it out with `swc`. If that doesn't work (maybe because you're doing something else that `swc` doesn't support), make sure that `@babel/preset-env` is included in your babel config.